# ARM Thumb-2 WFE instruction

Tags: c, arm

I am working with Cortex M3 ARM processor.So, I have a main loop like this;

```
while(true){

foo();
System_Watchdog_Refresh();
__ASM("wfe");//System wait for event...

}
```

So, manufacturer company said to me this;
If you don't want to reset your program from wdt(Watchdog Timer), you should set a empty timer ISR for every 1 ms.

There is problem for me here because  ı have used "System_Watchdog_Refresh();" function and yeah processor running this function every loop.How watchdog timer reset the processor in this state?

Note that:

- System_Watchdog_Refresh(): Reset wdt timer
- Wdt can't be disable
- foo() function doesn't matter for this state
- When ı remove "__ASM("wfe");" processor doesn't reset from wdt

Thank you...

Comment: What if there is no event for a longer time then the watchdog period?

Comment: I guess manufacturer company use ISR for this situation. I didn't understand this state on debug mode...

Comment: WFE sets the processor to standby until the next interrupt (or event). So even though you refresh the watchdog, the processor goes to sleep immediately after that and in the absence of any other events, stays in that state until the watchdog expires and resets the processor. To prevent that, you will need something that periodically triggers an interrupt (like an empty timer that the manufacturer suggests) to ensure the processor wakes up and resumes execution, thereby also refreshing the watchdog.

Comment: The timer interval should be something reasonably close to, but much less than, the watchdog timeout to ensure you get the ideal mix of power-saving and reliability.

Comment: @th33lf yeah this answer enough to me. Thank you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WFE sets the processor to standby until the next interrupt (or event). So even though you refresh the watchdog, the processor goes to sleep immediately after that and in the absence of any other events, stays in that state until the watchdog expires and resets the processor. To prevent that, you will need something that periodically triggers an interrupt (like an empty timer that the manufacturer suggests) to ensure the processor wakes up and resumes execution, thereby also refreshing the watchdog.

The timer interval should be something reasonably close to, but much less than, the watchdog timeout to ensure you get the ideal mix of power-saving and reliability.

(Moved my comments to an answer, since the OP says it works for him.)